# Bootstrap navbar objects on the left won't show on mobile

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, navbar

---

For some reason which I can't figure out, the bootstrap navbar buttons that I put on the left won't show when I'm on my phone (the ones on the right: "Home" and "Link 2", work just fine). Specifically the "Register and "Log in" buttons are broken.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light" style="margin-bottom:30px">
<a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Website name</a>
<button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
<span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
</button>
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
        <li class="nav-item active">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Start <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link 2 </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div class="navbar-collapse collapse w-100 order-3 dual-collapse2">
    <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="signup">Register</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="login">Log in</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't use two collapse divs. You can see it work if you just take out the second collapse div. Fiddle example below:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light" style="margin-bottom:30px">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Website name</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
<span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
</button>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Start <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link 2 </a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="signup">Register</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="login">Log in</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/Mikkal24/15ne7h85/